# How to Iterate in folders in a list in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list With contains folders upto 2 levels (ListItem -> Folder -> folder ->  list items)

how I can iterate a list like above using Javascript in Sharepoint 2013.

I can iterate base items but dont know how to iterate through list with lists

```
function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('newsList');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query>   <OrderBy>      <FieldRef Name='ID' />   </OrderBy></Query>");

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CAML Query ViewXml to:

```
<View Scope='Recursive'>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name='ID' />
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
</View>
```

and you should get all the items regardless of folder

Comment: although I was looking for a way to iterated folder by folder but this also solved my problem